# SharePoint : How to check for null with a CAML Query?

Tags: sharepoint

I have this CAML:

```
query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MessageID' /><Value Type='Text'></Value></Eq></Where>";
```

This checks if the value of MessageID = string.empty()

What I would like to check for is null.... not empty string...

Is this possible with CAML?

Comment: Wrapping an SQL-like querying language in XML: a stroke of genius, or pure malice? You decide.

Comment: It would work if it was SQL... but its another funky (broken) aspect of SharePoint. SharePoint never disappointments...

Comment: Also you have to love Microsofts documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588322%28office.11%29.aspx - explains everything else except how to use isnull....

Answer (score 57, accepted):

CAML has the IsNull operator,so the query would be:

```
query.Query = @"<Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name='MessageID' /></IsNull></Where>"
```

Comment: How does it not 'work' You could try using an Or statement, check for empty AND Null values?

Comment: P.S. what type is the field of anyway, it says MessageID. Is that an integer?

Comment: Its a string... but when I step through in code... and check the value... its null....

Comment: Did you add this field to the list later on? Because SharePoint doesn't update Existing items when the field is added, I guess you could describe it as "the field exists but no value has been assigned, not even Null"

Comment: Cool! P.S. how I know these things? Mainly through many frustrated hours :-D

Answer (score 26):

Needed an equivalent to `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Description)`. Ended up with this:

```
<And>
  <IsNotNull>  
    <FieldRef Name='Description' />   
  </IsNotNull>  
  <Neq>  
    <FieldRef Name='Description' />  
    <Value Type='Text'></Value>  
  </Neq>
</And>
```

Comment: note that it's negated IsNullOrEmpty before you copy and paste ;)

Answer (score 13):

Agree with Colin, and more often used condition are as following:

```
1. Null:
<Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name="CustomField" /></IsNull></Where>
2. Not Null:
<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="CustomField" /></IsNotNull></Where>
3. Equal:
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="CustomField" /><Value Type="Text">MatchValue</Value></Eq></Where>
4. Not Equal：
<Where><Neq><FieldRef Name="CustomField" /><Value Type="Text">MatchValue</Value></Neq></Where>
5. Greater Than：
<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name="CustomField" /><Value Type="Text">1</Value></Gt></Where>
6. Greater Than And Equal：
<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name="CustomField" /><Value Type="Text">1</Value></Geq></Where>
7. Lower Than:
<Where><Lt><FieldRef Name="CustomField" /><Value Type="Text">1</Value></Lt></Where>
8. Lower Than And Equal:
<Where><Leq><FieldRef Name="CustomField" /><Value Type="Text">1</Value></Leq></Where>
9 Begin With:
<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name="CustomField" /><Value Type="Text">StartString</Value></BeginsWith></Where>
10: Contains:
<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="CustomField" /><Value Type="Text">ContainString</Value></Contains></Where>
```

**Note**: More information please visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx
There is the fully Caml Query Schema.

Hope this can help you~

Answer (score 0):

You can Check for Nulls using: [IsNotNull element (Query)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/isnotnull-element-query).

> Used within a query to return items that are not empty (Null).

Example:

```
<IsNotNull>
   <FieldRef Name = "Field_Name"/>
   <Value Type = "Field_Type"/>
   <XML />
</IsNotNull>
```

You can Check for Nulls using: [IsNull element (Query)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/isnull-element-query).

> Used within a query to return items that are empty (Null).

Example:

```
<IsNull>
   <FieldRef Name = "Field_Name"/>
     <Value Type = "Field_Type"/>
   <XML />
</IsNull>
```